# getting JSON object from a GET cURL in php

Tags: php, json, curl, get

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init('');  

  $request = 'where={"place":"'.$place.'"}&count=1&limit=0';
  $url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/className" . "?" . $request;

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);



  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ...',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ...
    ));

  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);


  // Execute
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  // Close connection
  curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the output:

```
{"results":[],"count":0}
```

I want to get only he number in count.

I tried this:

```
$json_res = json_decode($result, true);

  echo 'Number : '.$json_res['count'];
```

but the output becomes:

```
Number :
```

If i do `json_encode` the result is just a `True` value.

I tried added this:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

but didn't change anything.

What am I missing?

EDIT: doing a var_dump on $json_res gives me that: `int(1)`.
Why is that?

Comment: Did you bother checking if json_decode() actually succeeded? It returns a php `null` on failure.

Comment: @MarcB hmm, how to check it? Maybe it does not succeed at all.

Comment: Do a var_dump of $json_res

Comment: `if ($json_res === null) { die(json_last_error()); }`. Of course, this can produce a false positive if you really DID send a valid "null" value as the json string.

Comment: @AlexBarroso it prints int(1).

Comment: @MarcB it is not null. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl does not return the output if you don't set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```